# Find a quadratic equation that approaches exponential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=1-y(x)-e^{-ay}
\end{equation}

I need to find a quadratic equation that approaches the right side of the equation. I know it's something along the lines of $-\frac{a^2}{2}y^2(x)+(a-1)y(x)$, but I don't know how you get there.

Comment: $e^{-ay} \approx 1 + \dfrac{-ay}{1!} + \dfrac{(-ay)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(-ay)^3}{3!}+\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

For small $a$, a good approximation of the term $e^{-ay}$ is given by

$$e^{-ay} = 1 - ay + \frac{(-ay)^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(a^3),
$$

which, if you plug it in to the right-hand side of your equation, will leave exactly

$$
y(a-1) - \frac{(ay)^2}{2}.
$$